# interactive graph and display options

Tags: java, python, api, graph, desktop

I'm developing a desktop app with python 2.7. I need to show some results on an interactive graph (tree view). First of all, the graph displays just the root and the next level children,  (the children for the next levels are hidden) the tree must show the children for an especific node once the user clicks on one of them, refreshing the entire tree on the same window. When the user reaches the last level, the app must provide a menu. I'm using Zest (java) and os.system(java...) for connecting java code with python, but I'm not 100% comfortable with it
Is there an api which I can use for creating interactivity in that way, like actionListeners or something? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check http://d3js.org/ for charting library.It is a javascript library whcih provides interactive charts.Is there any specific reason for using python??

If you are flexible enough to use javascript libraries you can use JavaFX and use javascript libraries to create interactive charts?

Otherwise you can check the source of these d3 charts and try to implement your chart in Python

There is also a way to communicate between phython and java . Use the following link
http://www.slideshare.net/onyame/mixing-python-and-java

There are a lot of open source charting libraries available for java, then you can use that libraries . follow the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081676/looking-for-open-source-tool-for-drawing-charts-in-java

Comment: I've got almost the whole project written in python. Can I use javascript libraries on a desktop app? I can use .jar in my app, actually I use apache lucene as an external api

Comment: Yes, you can use javascript libraries on a desktop app if your base is Java .JavaFX provides a way to make java calls from javascript and vice-versa.Refer the following links:http://rakeshmenonp.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/javafx-javascript-communication/
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_javascript.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_javascript.htm#BCEFHHIJ

Comment: My teacher told me to use Python a lot of time ago, and I didn't know python at all, this is my first project with python. I developed a lot of java apps before, but nothing related with graphs

Comment: is there a free version of javaFX? I think I need an account

Comment: Yes ,it is freely available on oracle. It is bundled in the jdk 1.7 update 6 otherwise you can install it separately.

Comment: A netbeans IDE bundled with JavaFx is available at following link:http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html